# Jersey Test Framework gives null pointer Exception

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a Jersey Rest resource and I want to create an integration test using the Jersey Test Framework. I decided to follow the guide from here (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) so I created the following integration test

```
public class MyResourceIT extends JerseyTest {

public MyResourceIT() {
}

@Path("hello")
public static class HelloResource {
    @GET
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

@Override
protected Application configure() {
    System.out.println("Configure was executed");
    return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class);
}

@Test
public void testGetIt() {
    System.out.println("getIt");
    final String hello = target("hello").request().get(String.class);
    assertEquals("Hello World!", hello);
}
}
```

As a container I used Jetty but the problem is that when I run the test I am getting the following error :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.example.jerseywebapp.MyResourceIT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.305 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.jerseywebapp.MyResourceIT
testGetIt(com.example.jerseywebapp.MyResourceIT)  Time elapsed: 0.169 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target(JerseyTest.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target(JerseyTest.java:580)
    at com.example.jerseywebapp.MyResourceIT.testGetIt(MyResourceIT.java:68)
```

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, the problem was that I used maven 1.x for everything else and maven 2.x for the jersey test framework.

Comment: Hmmm.  That doesn't work for me, at least not directly.  I'm have this exact same problem in gradle builds and leinighen builds.  If I take the Tests out of the "integration" group, all is well.  Arghhh.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue, but in my case it happened because my test class override the `setUp()` method which used by JerseyTest class to initialize its context.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below dependency and run your test. It works. Have you tried with this dependency?

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
   <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: With this dependency I get 2 errors : 

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;`

and 

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.tearDown(JerseyTest.java:634)`

Comment: My integration tests are in a separate maven submodule. I haven't configured jetty for this module. Do you have jetty in your integration test module?

Comment: No, I have added only the dependency you added above. The only change I did for the integration tests to my pom was to add the `maven-failsafe-plugin`.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to disable the jetty in project (also may be the maven-failsafe-plugin as well) and give it a try again?

Comment: Do you mean to remove completely the dependency that you added and run the tests are simple unit tests ?